# Difference of two lists

Tags: c#

I have two lists:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

list1 = {"a", "b", "b", "c", "b"};
list2 = {"b", "d", "c"};
```

I would like to get the differences in the following way:

```
list3 = list1 - list2 = {"a", "b", "b"};
list4 = list2 - list1 = {"d"};
```

I cannot use "Except" here because

```
list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

removes all accurences of string "b" in list1. I need *each* occurrence of a string in the second list only removes *one* occurrence of that string in the first list.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `Operator overloading` to Rescue

Comment: And which `"b"` should be removed? First, second, third? Or result order doesn't matter?

Comment: doesn't matter which "b" is removed, the order of the elements in the lists are completely unimportant

Comment: `list1 - list2` should be `"a", "b", "b"`, according to your specs (you remove one `b` and one `c`), shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
            List<string> list3 = list1;
            foreach (string d in list2) { list3.Remove(d); }
            List<string> list4 = list2;
            foreach (string d in list1) { list4.Remove(d); }
```

Comment: The algorithm is correct, but you probably want `List<string> list3 = new List<string>(list1);`, otherwise elements will be removed from the original list, and there's no point in using a different variable (you can just remove from `list1` directly)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

list1.Add("a");
list1.Add("b");
list1.Add("b");
list1.Add("c");
list1.Add("b");
list2.Add("b");
list2.Add("d");
list2.Add("c");

var resultList= temp(list2,list1);
}

List<string> temp(List<string> x,List<string> y)
{
foreach(var value in y)
{
    x.Remove((x.Where(z=>z == value).SelectMany(g=>g.Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty(g.First())).FirstOrDefault()).ToString());
}
return x;
}
```